# How to change screen text color in multiple PowerShell consoles using ConEmu version 171217 64-bit?

Tags: powershell, colors, conemu

I want to have each PowerShell console to have different screen text color. Using ConEmu version 171217 64-bit and multiple PowerShell consoles at a time,  I have tried changing text screen color in each of PowerShell console with no success.
I have tried as follows:
1) Go to settings (Win +All + P). However, it is here where I do not know the steps to set distinct screen color text in each PowerShell console: 
- Go to upper right menu
- Set up Tasks
- Features
- App distinct.

2)
- Right click on tab
- Debug
-  Properties
- Colors (tab)
- Check on “Screen Text” button and select a color from the color array selection. It changes the screen text color OK. However, after closing and opening ConEmu application, it goes back to the previous default screen text color.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't understand what do you want. But you definitely must not go to Debug menu.

Comment: Hi @Maximus. I use multiple PowerShell consoles at a time. I would like every PowerShell console  to have its distinct screen text. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting the color from within the Debug menu, you are only setting the colors up for that session. ConEmu's colors are controlled from Settings (`Win+Alt+P`) -> Features -> Colors.

To maintain separate colors for separate processes, create a new Task (`Win+Alt+T`) that uses `-new_console` [switches](https://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html).

A modification of the above documentation's first example, where "Palette" is your pallet name:

```
powershell.exe -new_console:P:"Palette"
```

Comment: Thank you @root. I use multiple PowerShell consoles at a time. I have tried Settings (Win +All + P). However, it is here where I do not know the steps to set distinct screen color text in each PowerShell console.

Comment: Answer has been modified. Your comment adds more clarity to your original question.  You should edit your question and add these details so people can better provide answers.

Comment: The solution was what?

Comment: Thank you, root. solution:    
1) Settings. 2) Features-Colors. "Schemes" type a name (i.e. scheme1). Text button, enter color number(i.e. #14).Press "Save". 3) Similar to step 2. "Schemes" name (i.e. scheme2), color text (i.e. #13).  4) Startup -Tasks. 5) Press the "+" and assign task name (i.e. 2screens)                                      6) in bottom pane, example:
powershell -new_console:P:"scheme1" -new_console:s50H
powershell -new_console:P:"scheme2"  -new_console:s50H   
7) Save settings